# DRF - Nested Serializer Writing Data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is the model

```
class Memo(BaseModel):
    memo_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    is_tag_new = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'memo'

class Link(BaseModel):
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    memo = models.ForeignKey('Memo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='url')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'link'
```

I have a serializer with nested serializer fields like this

```
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ['url']

class MemoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    urls = LinkSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    memo_mark = BookmarkSerializer(read_only=True)
    tag_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    tag_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_images(self, obj):
        image = obj.image_set.all()
        return ImageSerializer(instance=image, many=True, context=self.context).data

    class Meta:
        model = Memo
        fields = ['id', 'memo_text', 'is_tag_new', 'memo_mark', 'images', 'urls',
                  'tag_name', 'tag_color', 'tag', 'created_at', 'updated_at']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = Memo.objects.create(**validated_data)
        urls_data = validated_data.pop('urls')
        images_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        if images_data is not None:
            for images_data in images_data.getlist('image'):
                Image.objects.create(memo=instance, image=images_data)
        if urls_data is not None:
            for urls_data in urls_data:
                Link.objects.create(memo=instance, **urls_data)
        return instance
```

my first problem is that urls is not showing up
instead, it shows up like this

```
{
            "id": 39,
            "memo_text": null,
            "is_tag_new": false,
            "images": [],
            "tag_name": "URL",
            "tag_color": "BL",
            "tag": 4,
            "created_at": "2022-01-04T04:17:56.221539",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-04T04:17:56.221539"
}
```

the second problem is writing datas to this nested serializer. uploading multiple image works fine, however saving multiple url isn't working. This picture is of my error
[url error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwZM9.png)

my total expectation is something like this

```
{
            "id": 39,
            "memo_text": null,
            "is_tag_new": false,
            "images": [],
            "urls" : [
                {
                    "url" : "https://google.com/"
                }
            ],
            "tag_name": "URL",
            "tag_color": "BL",
            "tag": 4,
            "created_at": "2022-01-04T04:17:56.221539",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-04T04:17:56.221539"
}
```

I assume that overriding the create method is the reason that writing data to the serializer isn't working, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
How should I change my code to make it work?

Comment: On the first json, it the response for which POST query ? Can you had it ?
For point #2, maybe try to pop 'urls' _before_ instanciating the Memo object in create() method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.